# Adding Category in URL in some post

Tags: plugins, permalinks

I have some permalinks in wordpress site and i want to add category to the URL , like `mydomain.com/category/remainig post name` ,

I don't want to change the structure of all other post keeping them without category 
Any Leads most welcome or any plugin

Comment: it will be same like writing for each and every URL i want something like , if i have a post tagged category : ENGLISH then it should be url/english/postname , if any other category is there then it should not add it to url

Answer (score 0):

[This plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-permalinks/) should allow you to to set a permalink structure of domain/target_category/post, while leaving the permalink structure for the rest of your links as domain/post.

If you only want to change a few posts/pages and not the others within a category, I would just edit those and change the permalink manually.

Answer (score -2):

```
$var = explode("/", get_the_permalink());
echo $var[3];
```

OR

```
get_category();
```

Comment: Exploding the permalink is not a reliable or advised method to get the category. This answer also does not provide a way to add it to the permalink as OP requests.